# Display multiple user inputs Python

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm pretty new to Pyton. 
So I'm trying to make a gui that displays multiple user inputs. I've managed to do it with two inputs (text and number):

class Product:

```
db_name = 'mydatabase.db'

def __init__(self, wind):
    self.wind=wind
    self.wind.title('Date pacienti')

    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text='Add new record')
    frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Label(frame, text='Name:').grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.name = Entry(frame)
    self.name.grid(row=1, column =2)

    Label(frame, text='Last name:').grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.last = Entry(frame)
    self.last.grid(row=2, column =2)

    Label(frame, text = 'Age:').grid(row=3, column=1)
    self.age=Entry(frame)
    self.age.grid(row=3, column=2)

    Label(frame, text = 'Something else:').grid(row=4, column=1)
    self.else=Entry(frame)
    self.else.grid(row=4, column=2)

    ttk.Button(frame, text='Add record', command = self.adding).grid (row=5,column=2)
    self.message=Label(text='', fg='red')
    self.message.grid(row=3, column=0)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview (height=10, columns=2)
    self.tree.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2)
    self.tree.heading('#0',text = 'Name', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading(2, text='Last name', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading(3, text = 'Age', anchor=W)
    self.tree.heading(4, text='Something else', anchor=W)

    self.viewing_records ()


def run_query(self, query, parameters =()):
    with sqlite3.connect (self.db_name) as conn:
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
         conn.commit()
    return query_result


def viewing_records (self):
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete (element)
    query = 'SELECT * FROM pacienti ORDER BY nume DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query (query)
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], value = row[3])
```

I want to add more text fields for the user to input (e.g. text = row[2], row[4]... ).
How would I go about it?

Comment: can u show more of  your code

Comment: And "don't really seem to work" is a poor problem description. Please elaborate so it's possible for us to help you.